# JDK not found by VS Code

Tags: java, visual-studio

I have installed the Java JDK with the following command: `sudo apt install openjdk-18-jre` and in the terminal I can run `java --version` without a problem.

But whenever I open a Java project in VS Code I get these two error messages:

> Sorry, something went wrong activating IntelliCode support for Java. Please check the "Language Support for Java" and "VS IntelliCode" output windows for details.

> The java.jdt.ls.java.home variable defined in Visual Studio Code settings points to a missing or inaccessible folder (/usr/lib/jvm/java-18-openjdk-amd64)

I did add the following line to the settings.json:

```json
"java.jdt.ls.java.home": "/usr/lib/jvm/java-18-openjdk-amd64"
```

which I assume to being correct as `readlink -f $(which java)` yields `/usr/lib/jvm/java-18-openjdk-amd64/bin/java`.

Comment: Have you tried closing/opening your VS Code again?

It might be the updated environment variables not being picked up by VS Code.

Comment: Unfortunately neither restarting VS Code nor my PC did the trick.